# Why does jExcelAPI dump warnings in stderr and how to stop this behaviour?

Tags: java, logging, stderr, jexcelapi

While trying to read an xls file using jExcelAPI, I find that the library dumps a lot of information in stderr, sometimes this information is not relevant.  For example, this code snippet causes lots of 'Warnings' to be dumped on stderr stream:

```
    Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(flname));


    //For each sheet in the workbook
    for (int currentSheet = 0; currentSheet < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); currentSheet++)
    {
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(currentSheet);
        System.out.println("Currently processing " + sheet.getName());
    }
```

The warnings are like:

```
Currently processing frst sheet
Warning:  Cell C33680 already contains data
Warning:  Cell D33680 already contains data
Warning:  Cell E33680 already contains data
Warning:  Cell F33680 already contains data
Warning:  Cell B33680 already contains data
Currently processing Lst Sheet
```

How to avoid the library from dumping all this unwanted data?  Also I do not understand why the code even looks at all the cells of the sheet, when all I am asking for it to do is list the name of the sheets (I understand that Workbook.getSheetNames() can do a similar task - but say I wanted to print the name of the sheet and contents of a single cell in the sheet).

Am I using the library incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used this library, however quick look at [Logger.initializeLogger()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sourceforge.jexcelapi/jxl/2.6.12/jxl/common/Logger.java#Logger.initializeLogger%28%29) it looks like by default it tries to Log using Log4J. Do you have Log4J on your CLASSPATH? You can also use [SLF4J bridge](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html).

When you successfully redirect JExcelAPI into logging framework, you can configure which messages are dumped (and where).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out.  It seems that by default all the message are directed to standard streams - but if the library is rebuilt with logger options, then we can use it.  But still not very sure why does the function even look at all this data!