# How to stop jExcelAPI warnings in stderr

Tags: java, logging, jexcelapi

When I use jxl api and during read the content of .xls file the api print lots of warning messages to standard output. Is there any way to stop this function? 
This question is the same [Why does jExcelAPI dump warnings in stderr and how to stop this behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860834/why-does-jexcelapi-dump-warnings-in-stderr-and-how-to-stop-this-behaviour)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jExcelAPI dump warnings in stderr and how to stop this behaviour?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860834/why-does-jexcelapi-dump-warnings-in-stderr-and-how-to-stop-this-behaviour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. For more information please check [disable jxl library warnings](http://learningbitsandbytes.blogspot.com/2013/01/suppressing-jxl-warnings.html)

```
File myfile = new File("...");
WorkbookSettings settings = new WorkbookSettings();
settings.setSuppressWarnings(true);
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(myfile, settings);
```

Answer (score 0):

WorkbookSettings did not work for me but passing this argument to the JVM suppressed all warnings: `-Djxl.nowarnings=true`